# When are deleted entities written to the eclipselink UnitOfWorkChangeSet?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, audit-logging

I am trying to obtain the list of deleted entities in a database operation, to implement a custom auditing. Unfortunately it is not enough to just override the `remove` method of the `EntityManager`, because of cascading deletes.

I was able to find new and updated entities by utilizing the `EntityManager` and its `UnitOfWorkChangeSet`. Curiously the list of deleted entities is always empty.

I suspect the way the client invoke the method to be problematic, but am not quite sure. The client removes items from a collection of entities of an entity by removing them on the object and than calling the `persist` method with the entity holding the collection. This approach works in terms of removing the objects from the database by utilizing the cascade mechanism, but I can't find the removed entities in the list of deleted objects.

**Accessing deleted entities in changeset:**

```
Map<ObjectChangeSet, ObjectChangeSet> deletedObjects =
        entityManager.unwrap(UnitOfWork.class)
        .getCurrentChanges()
        // returns always an empty list
        .getDeletedObjects();

  return deletedObjects.values().stream()
        .map(v -> v.getUnitOfWorkClone())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This code is executed every time the `persist` method is invoked. It always returns an empty list.

Why does `getDeletedObjects()` always return an empty list and when does an entity get added to this list?

Comment: Try calling flush on the EntityManager and then getUnitOfWorkChangeSet  after unwrapping the UnitOfWork or  getCumulativeUOWChangeSet after unwrapping to RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.

Comment: This doesn't work either. `getDeletedObjects()` still returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Management summary**

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.delete(entity);
final Map deletedObjects = 
    ((RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork) entityManager
        .unwrap(UnitOfWork.class)).getDeleted();
// process deleted objects
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

**Explanation**

***Disclaimer**: I am bound to an ancient version (2.0.2) of eclipse-link, therefore this solution is probably outdated.*

My first fault was, trying to obtain the deleted objects outside of the transaction. While this approach works for new and modified objects, it does not for deleted objects.

My second fault was trying to access the `currentChanges`. While debugging, I discovered, that the method `getCurrentChanges()` is executed on the correct change set with my deleted objects, but yields a changeset without them. Therefore it is necessary to cast the unwrapped `UnitOfWork` to a `RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork`. In later versions, it might be possible to unwrap directly to this class, as hinted by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496099/chris). After casting, I was able to access the list of deleted objects directly.